# How can you change the appearance of a line (edge) with a tikz graph drawing algorithm written in Lua?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lua, tikz-graphdrawing

In my graph drawing algorithm (written in Lua for LuaLaTeX), I'd like to change a solid line to a dashed line. I use a `Digraph` with some vertices and arcs between them. On page 499 of the Tikz & PGF manual, it talks about a field `generated_options` that an `Arc` has. The `generated_options` will be passed to its `edges`, which in turn will be passed down to the display layer. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
arc.generated_options = {{key = "dashed", value="true"}}
```

But this doesn't do anything. *What am I missing here?*

I can make the line dashed in the `\graph`:

(the `tree layout` is used here, but I'm using my own layout)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout]
\graph{
  "Start"[rectangle, draw] --[dashed]
  "End"[rectangle, draw]
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'd like my Lua algorithm to change it to dashed instead. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE for the graph drawing code?
The TikZ manual says:

 _Similar to the path field below, the options set in this table are written back to the 
syntactic edges during a **sync.**_

Syncs are performed automatically only for certain types of graphs, see manual.